# If two matrices commute with a nonscalar matrix resp., they commute with each other

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A \in M_2(\mathbb C)$ be an arbitrary matrix which is not scalar. (In what follows the matrices are elements of $M_2(\mathbb C)$.) Then let $X := \{B \mid AB = BA\}$.  Here I would like to show that if $S,T\in X$, $ST = TS$.

I figured out that the condition that $A$ is not scalar is equivalent to saying that $X$ is properly contained in $M_2(\mathbb C)$, and that $X$ is closed under multiplication, but I  cannot go any further.

I would appreciate for your help.

Comment: If  $A$ has two distinct eigenvalues, it is diagonalizable: then you can show that any $B$ commuting with $A$ is diagonalizable in the same basis, and the result follows. So it only remains to consider the case of a nontrivial Jordan block, whose cummutant is not difficult to determine.

Comment: Is it well-known that any B commuting with A is diagonalizable in the same basis?

Comment: Precision: if $A$ has two distinct  eigenvalues, it is diagonalizable with one dimensional eigenspaces. If $B$ commutes with $A$, it leaves these eigenspaces invariant and so it must be diagonal in a diagonalization basis of $A$. Of course, this is not true if $A$ is just diagonalizable in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to post the solution Julien indicated, in detail:

$2\times 2$ matrices are either:

1. diagonalizable with repeated eigenvalues (scalar)
2. diagonalizable with different eigenvalues, or
3. non-diagonalizable, i.e. similar to

$$\left ( \begin {matrix} \lambda &1\\0 &\lambda \end {matrix} \right ). $$

The question deletes case #1. For case #2, if a $2\times 2$ matrix is diagonalizable with non-repeated eigenvalues, it has a spectral decomposition

$$A = \lambda_1 P_1 + \lambda_2 P_2, \text { for } P_1 + P_2 = I \text { a resolution of identity}.$$

If $B$ commutes with $A$, then it commutes with each projection $P_i$; therefore, $B$ preserves the one-dimensional spaces $\operatorname{range}{P_i}$. Therefore these are eigenspaces for $B$. So $B$ is diagonalizable with respect to the same basis as $A$. This relation is clearly transitive, and the problem is solved in case #2.

For case #3, $A$ is similar to $\lambda I + N$, for $N$ a $2\times 2$ nilpotent Jordan block. If $PAP^{-1}=\lambda I + N$, denote by $B'$ the matrix $PBP^{-1}$. Since $\lambda I$ commutes with everything, a matrix $B'$ commutes with $\lambda I + N$ iff it commutes with $N$. It can be shown that the only matrices which commute with $N$ are polynomials in $N$, i.e. of the form $a_0I + a_1N$ (these are the only polynomials since $N^2 =0$).

So if $B_1$ and $B_2$ commute with $A$, then $PB_1P^{-1}$ and $PB_1P^{-1}$ are both polynomials in $N$, and so they commute with each other. So $B_1$ and $B_2$ commute with each other, ending case #3.